# System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException "A relative URI cannot be created because the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute"

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model

The client object model code in my application is throwing the following exception. How to solve it?.

> System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service
>   '/_vti_bin/client.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during
>   compilation.  The exception message is: A relative URI cannot be
>   created because the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute
>   URI.http://Servername.DomainName:10000/_vti_bin/client.svc. --->
>   System.UriFormatException: A relative URI cannot be created because
>   the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute
>   URI.http://Servername.DomainName:10000/_vti_bin/client.svc

Answer (score 1):

try using a short url such as without the domain name and port information

Comment: Hi Joseph thanks for the reply. I tried using the short url, still the same exception. Any idea?

Comment: Try using a path is is basically saying it cannot find the root directory of the relative path to the server. Depending on where your web application is hosted if it is hosted within the same IIS website as your site you need to use a relative url to access your service. example if your site is located in /Site and your service is in /Services then the path to your webinvoke method would be /Site/Services/Service.svc/WebInvokeMethodName I hope this helps

Comment: Absolute would include the domain name and port and relative will point to a path where the root of the path is relative to the site